# ASP/C# - insert textbox in new line after other specific element

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a page with a set of elements.
I would like my `dropdownlist1` to create new textbox under another specific element.
For example, if I have (from top to bottom):

- Label1
- dropdownlist1
- textbox1
- dropdownlist2
- label2

I would like my **dropdownlist1** to create **textbox2** under **dropdownlist2** when user selects some item in the **dropdownlist1**.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to give your texbox2 initially display="none" property in CSS and place it where you want. Then create method, which will set it CSS property to for example 'inline-block' after assigning non-default value to variable which dropdownlist1 will set.

Comment: thanks for the reply,
I don't really think it's a good idea for couple of reasons:
1. it will do unwanted I/O on server/page to draw this hiddent textbox...because even if it is hidden it uses memory...I would like to be more effective with this.
2. even if the textbox is hidden, it takes a place in the page and seems like there is big empty space...
So I guess it should be creating the textbox when needed and not just hide/show...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

don't bother...
I found the answer...
I should create an empty DIV between the elements I'm interested and when the dropdownlist changes to specific option, the code behond (C#) will create the new textbox in the empty DIV